# MySQL - can connect via "reverse engineer" but not by double-clicking the connection using the same connection info

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

A connection to MySQL Server on the same network fails when double-clicking the connection in MySQL Workbench (i.e. trying to connect the standard way).  It gives the error message:

> "Cannot Connect to Database Server.  Your connection attempt failed for user 'xxxxxx" to the MySQL server at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306: Lost connection to MySQL server during query".

However, in the same MySQL Workbench, if I tell it to do Database -> Reverse Engineer and use that same connection that fails by double-clicking, it works just fine instantly and is able to retrieve the remote schema details.  Python also connects just fine and can run a query and display the results.  MySQL command-line client cannot connect (it just hangs).

Workbench can connect to the local MySQL instance just fine when double clicking the connection, just not the remote one.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Workbench as well as removing the antivirus and reverting to Windows Defender and rebooting but nothing worked.  Initially when double clicking the connection using the default settings of SSL set to "if required", I'd get an error message of:

> "SSL connection error: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)"

But after turning SSL to "No" to eliminate that as a potential problem, then the behavior described above is what happened.

I also tried creating a new connection and even a new user account but no luck.

This is using MySQL Workbench 8.x connecting to MySQL Server 8.x.

Comment: the mysql server also has to allow that remote computers can log in to the server(for example grant for the user that has to log in) also the firewall has to let remote connection in

Comment: @nbk Yes, both of those are good since I'm able to connect from this same machine to the server via both Python and "Reverse Engineer" from MySQL Workbench, just not by double-clicking the connection in Workbench.  That should effectively rule out any firewall / network / user+host permission issues as far as I know.  Thanks

Comment: there is simply something wrong. delete the connection and create a new one, sometimes there are typos or not seen characters.

Comment: @nbk I tried creating a new connection and even a new user account but no luck

Comment: then you must go deeper, wireshark to monitor the network connection, Wiresharl on both sides monitor the packages that are transfered, the interprtation us somewhat tricky, but ysou will see a ping pong between both sides, with out any errors. second enable general log in the mysql server to see if something reaches the server at all. and if something is stuck